# Абстракция или конкретная реализация?

Tags: java

В книге Философия Java не раз употребляется фраза вроде:

> Вспомните совет, данный в конце предыдущей главы: отдавать
>   предпочтение классам перед интерфейсами. Если архитектура системы
>   требует применения интерфейса, вы это поймете. В остальных случаях не
>   применяйте интерфейсы без крайней необходимости.

Вместе с тем, почти во всех книга по ООП и паттернам говорится, что предпочтение всегда (!) должно отдаваться абстракции, а не реализации.

Реального опыта программирования на Java не имею, поэтому такие противоречивые высказывания сбивают с толку. Кому верить ?

Comment: зависит от задач, например, если тебе нужна одна база, один механизм i\o, то, действительно, зачем интерфейсы, лучше сразу абстракции. Однако, если у тебя 6 видов БД, то тут конечно же использовать интерфейсы. 
P.s. это является просто примером, каждая задача должна рассматриваться отдельно

Comment: @SeniorAutomator да, но во многих книгах сказано, что сани надо готовить заренее. То есть, всегда нужно быть готовым к изменениям и расширениям, даже в небольших проектах...

Comment: правильный спроектированный контроллер позволит работать в несколькими базами, например, tibero, mysql ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Далее в книге есть такие слова:

> "В общем случае рекомендуется отдавать предпочтение классам перед ин­терфейсами. Начните с классов, а если необходимость интерфейсов станет оче­видной — переработайте архитектуру своего проекта. Интерфейсы — замеча­тельный инструмент, но ими нередко злоупотребляют."

Однако если проект разросся до огромных размеров, то фраза "переработайте архитектуру" выглядит очень сомнительной. Как-от слабо себе представляю большой проект в котором так легко можно сказать "переработайте архитектуру." Это как раз тот вид ошибок, который трудно исправлять.  По-моему мнению, даже если существует только одна реализация - то лучше применять интерфейс. Кроме того, обычно интерфейсы сопровождаются вынесением зависимостей классов друг от друга во внешний ресурс (например, в xml файл) - что в больших проектах есть необходимость.